# Difference between inside and on the inside

Tags: meaning, word-usage

So I stumbled across these two sentences

> when you are low-key dead on the inside ...
>
> They look low-key dead inside

What's the difference between inside and on the inside? I don't seem to find the difference at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including the prepositional element *(**on the**)* could be said to impart "emphasis", but I think it's only really appropriate in contexts where ***inside*** is being (more or less explicitly) contrasted with ***outside***.

That's to say, ***He felt dead inside*** has no real implications for how he felt "outside" (which isn't even a very meaningful thing to say anyway), but ***He felt dead on the inside*** would normally only occur in a context where ***on the outside*** (his external appearance) there was no evidence of this.

Apart from that there's no real difference, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt%20dead%20inside%2Cfelt%20dead%20on%20the%20inside&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20dead%20inside%3B%2Cc0) should make it clear that native speakers usually prefer the simpler (prepositionless) form.